# how to access to foreign attributes model in django views

Tags: python, django

This is my code:

urls.py

```
url(r'^blog/$', views.blog, name='blog'),
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
  Status = ((1, "Publicado"), (2, "Borrador"), (3, "Eliminado"))
  status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status, default=3)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='prueba')
  description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  content = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos", default=1)
  autor = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

views.py

```
def blog(request):
  posts = Post.objects.filter(status=1).values().order_by("-creation_date")
  categories = Category.objects.order_by("name")
  context = {
    "posts":posts,
    "categories":categories
  }
  return render(request, "blog.html", context)
```

blog.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <a href="{% url 'detail_post' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
  <p>{{ post.category }}</p>
  <p>{{ post.autor }}</p>
  <p>{{ post.creation_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't access to the attributes author and category from a post.
Please. I need help for how to do it.
I need fix the problem.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please write `autor` -> `author`?

Comment: For your code, `{{ post.autor }}` and `{{ post.category }}` should show the string representations of the related user and category. If that's not working, you should explain what you are getting and what you expect.

Comment: The output show only the three attributes from Post, not the autor and the category:
- Prueba 1 Post
- Descripción Prueba 1 Post
- 26 de Febrero de 2018 a las 13:31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this in your template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail_post' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
    {% for category in post.category.all %}
        <p>{{ category.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for author in post.author.all %}
        <p>{{ author.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ post.creation_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: I might be a bit late for this, did you find an answer yet? Else I'll try to help the best I can

Comment: solved: `{{ post.category.name }}` and `{{ post.author.username }}`